# Items from file in itemize environment

Tags: latex

Is possible import items from file on itemize environment? For example, I have one file like this:

```
Elem1
Elem2
Elem3
Elem4
...
Elem120933
```

I want to put all this elements on itemize in my document. Have I to copy manually all elements? Any other way?

Comment: See my answer on http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256689/31729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using Excel.

1. Open file by excel. Each data will be placed in cells in "A" column. Elem1 will be placed into cell "A1", Elem2 into cell "A2" ,,, Elem120933 into cell "A120933".
2. Write a function in following into cell "B1".

```
     = "  /item " & A1
```

Cell "B1" will become '  /item Elem1'

1. select "B1", 
   Copy "B1",
   scroll down until "B120933" cell appeard on screen,
   push down shift key, and click "B120933" cell while shift key is down. All cells between "B1" and "B120933" will be selected,
   then paste (push control key and "V" key at same time.

   You will get items part of latex in B column.

4.
   select "A" column by clicking "A" at top (above "A1" cell).
   Delete "A" column.

5.
   Save excel file as CSV file.
   The csv file saved contains item part of latex.

This operation may be much easier then copy 120933 items manually.

CAUTION:
  I use excel 1013 and that can handle 120933 lines of data, but excel before 2003 can handle upto 65536 lines.
  If use excel 2003 or older, repeat operation.
At first operation, you can get latex source of 65535 items.
Then delete first 65535 lines from text file and save with othername (data2.txt as example).
Repeat operation with text file "data2.txt" for getting another latex source of 55398　items.　(55398=120933-65535)

I hope this answer give you some spare time.

Comment: I say 120933 as example. Thanks for your time and answer.